# How to know when the download begins and ends in filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I want to make an animation, so when the download begins the animation too, and the download ends and also the animation, but the function saveAs() is not a promise and returns void(or undefined), so, the only way to know if the download is ready is when the file explorer appears.

how I can know when the download begins and ends??
I'm just downloading images

// I try with

```
saveAs(myBlob,filename).then( returnValue => doSomething() )
// but saveAs() is not a promise
```

I want to know when the download begins and ends to begin and end my animation

Comment: The answers there were not specific to *filesaver.js*, but filesaver does use <a download> (when available). Since there is no way to tell from this, obviously filesaver.js can't tell either.

Comment: hey, I add a callback in the functions, so when the download ends, the callback is executed,
check this  https://github.com/carlosEdua/img2save/blob/master/src/utilities/filesaver.js